# Rounding numbers considering all the digits

Tags: java, rounding

In java code I have 1 input being :16275.874999999998

I build a method which rounds it up to: 16275.87

But the right answer is: 16275.88

How do I fix that in Java?

My current rounding method:

```
public static double round(final double value, final int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

Edit: I thought "the right answer" had .88 because the 9s would round up but that's not the case with the method I am using, will definitely look into rewrite it to consider previous decimal points.

Many thanks for the replies everyone!

Comment: How is rounding `16275.874999999998` to `16275.88` the correct answer if you're using the rounding mode HALF_UP? If you round to 2 places then `.874xxx` will be rounded to `.87` not matter the `xxx` part - it's in the lower half of the range.

Comment: "But the right answer is: 16275.88" <- no, rounding does not work that way. Your number is closer to 16275.87 and therefor gets correctly rounded to that value

Comment: If 16275.874999999998 is the imprecise result of a calculation, and should have been 16275.875, i.e. it is off by one [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place), then do the calculation using `BigDecimal`, not `double`. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5221149)

Comment: In maths, when you are rounding a number you start from the end of it. This method obviously doesn't and I thought it did. My fault for not checking the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Java is actually rounding your number correctly.  Since you're rounding to 2 places, the setScale method looks at the third decimal spot which is 4 in your example.  Since 4 < 5, your HALF_UP rounding mode will behave like ROUND_DOWN, which is why your output is 16275.87 instead of 16275.88

In order for your number to round up to 16275.88, you would need to run your method with input as `round(round(16275.874999999998, 3), 2)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to always round up then you need to use `RoundingMode.CEILING` or `RoundingMode.UP` (depending on how you want negative numbers to behave), instead of `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`

```java
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.CEILING);
```

`HALF_UP` will round up for anything with 5 or over in the first decimal place that is getting discarded and round down for anything less than 5 in that position.

`CEILING` and `UP` will always round up for positive numbers so 16275.871 will round to 16275.88. The difference between the two is how they handle negative numbers. `CEILING` rounds towards the positive numbers and `UP` will round towards the larger negative number.

```
CEILING of -16275.871 = -16275.871
UP of -16275.871 = -16275.88
```